# Expression for the expectation of Integrated variance in case of GARCH(1,1) process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, variance, sde

I have the following SDE (GARCH(1,1)) for the instantaneous variance:

$$ d\sigma_t^2 = \kappa (\theta - \sigma_t^2) dt + \psi \sigma_t^2 dW_t $$

I would like to find an expression for $IV_t = E[\int_{t-1}^t \sigma_{\tau}^2 d\tau]$.

Here is my reasoning:

$E[\int_{t-1}^t \sigma_{\tau}^2 d\tau] = \int_{t-1}^t E[\sigma_{\tau}^2]d\tau $

If I integrate directly the SDE between 0 and $\tau$, I get:
$$ \sigma_\tau^2 = \sigma_0^2 + \int_0^\tau \kappa (\theta-\sigma_t^2)dt + \int_0^\tau \psi \sigma_t^2 dW_t $$
Taking the expectation, I get:
$$ E[\sigma_\tau^2] = \sigma_0^2 + \kappa \theta \tau - \kappa \int_0^\tau E[\sigma_t^2] dt $$

I was hoping here to obtain a simplified expression for $E[\sigma_\tau^2]$ and then inject into the integral. However that did not simplify.

Does anyone know how can I get an expression for $IV_t$?